# Update VBO or use uniforms?

Tags: opengl, vbo, vertex-shader, vertices

Let's say I've got hundreds of rectangles on my scene. Each of them is changing each frame:

- they move over scene, they rotate, scale up/down
- vertices's color changes and should be combined with texture's color
- textures coordinates changes because those are 2D animations

How should I do it to get the best performance? There are my ideas. Please help me choose which is the best of them or suggest something else:

- update VBO each frame
- make more vertices than need (example: store all animation's frames in VBO) and choose which is rendered (call glDrawElements many times)
- send changing data via uniforms and recalculate it in vertex shader instead of CPU

The main question actually is: which functions can I call as many times as I want and which I should avoid calling more than few time per main loop?

Comment: VBO? you mean VAO?  in your case, take a look at  [instanced rendering](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial33/tutorial33.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the model remains the same in its local space so you only need to upload it once to the VBO. Changes such as translations, rotations, scaling, etc are performed by loading corresponding transformation matrices into uniforms and using them in the shaders.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. What about calling glDrawElements lots of times?  Let's say I have 2D animation and all ~100 frames in one VBO. Each main loop I'd like to render just 2 triangles from that VBO. Is that good idea? The other way is keep 2 triangles in VBO and update theirs texture coordinates or pass them via uniform. I know everything will work fine but what about performance in each way?

Comment: It's difficult to predict because different GPUs/drivers will behave differently. If you are just rendering a couple of different triangles each frame and the VBO remains unchanged you should be ok. But then again a smaller VBO and uniform update is also something that drivers handle well so I can't tell which will work better. My suggestion to you is first to find out where your perf bottleneck is and only then address it.